# Measuring volumes with oil drums of 8 and 5 litre

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, decanting-problems

You have two drums of capacity 8 litre and 5 litre and a resource of oil, can you use these two drums to give 1 litre, 2 litre, 3 litre, 4 litre, and 6 litres and 7 litres to any customer? If yes, then how?
Note that there is no mark of litres on the drums.

Comment: anyone seen Die Hard w a Vengeance? :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> yes, you can, mainly because 5 and 8 are relatively prime (and the required volumes are less than the combined volume of the drums)

Reasoning:

> 1. use the procedure for 6. below, empty [5], put 5 liter in [5] (then it's full) and you're left with 1 liter in [8].
>  2. fill [5], empty it in [8], fill [5] again, put 3 liter in [8] (then it's full) and you're left with 2 liter in [5].
>  3. fill [8], put 5 liter in [5] (then it's full) and you're left with 3 liter in [8].
>  4. use the procedure for 7. below, fill [5], put 1 liter in [8] (then it's full) and you're left with 4 liter in [5].
>  6. use the procedure for 3., empty [5], put the 3 liter from [8] in [5], fill [8], put 2 liter in [5] (then it's full) and you're left with 6 liter in [8].
>  7. use the procedure for 2., empty [8], put the 2 liter from [5] in [8], fill [5] and empty it in [8]. You're left with 7 liter in [8].

Answer (score 1):

1. Fill up the 5 liter, and pour all of it into the 8 liter.
2. Fill up the 5 liter again, and pour into the 8 liter until it's full. There will be 2 liters left in the 5 liter. *Two liter check!*
3. Empty the 8 liter, and pour the two liters from the 5 liter into the 8 liter.
4. Fill the 5 liter, and pour it all into the 8 liter, which now contains 7 liters. *7 liter check!*
5. Empty the 5 liter, and refill it. Pour into the 8 liter until it's full. There will be 4 liters left in the 5 liter. *4 liter check!*
6. Empty the 8 liter, and pour the four liters from the 5 liter into the 8 liter.
7. Fill the 5 liter, and pour into the 8 liter until it's full. Now the 5 liter will contain 1 liter. *1 liter check!*

Now, we have measured 1, 2, 4, and 7 correctly. We just need 3 and 6.

1. Fill the 8 liter, and pour into the 5 liter until it's full. Now we have 3 left over in the 8 liter. *3 liter check!*
2. Empty the 5 liter out, and pour the remaining 3 liters into it.
3. Fill the 8 liter, and pour into the 5 liter until it's full. Now we have 6 left over in the 8 liter *6 liter check!*